# How can I find objects with same keys values in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
  const arr = [
    { type: 'type', fields: ['field1'] },
    { type: 'type2' },
    { type: 'type', fields: ['field2'] },
  ]
```

And I need to find objects with the same type to merge fields key in them, like this:

```
  const arr = [
    { type: 'type', fields: ['field1', 'field2'] },
    { type: 'type2' },
    { type: 'type', fields: ['field1', 'field2'] },
  ]
```

My plan was to filter through the array, but my problem is that I don't know which type will send me API, so filtering by `item.type` wouldn't work for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+merge+values+with+same+key+object+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the exact solution that you want. Following code snippet may help you.

```
    const arr = [
      { type: 'type', fields: ['field1']},
      { type: 'type2'},
      { type: 'type', fields: ['field2']}
    ]
    
    const modifyArr = (data) => {
      let res = [];
      arr.map((item) => {
          if(item.type == data.type){
            if(Object.keys(item).includes('fields')){
              res = res.concat(item.fields);
            }
          }
      });
      return Object.keys(data).includes('fields') ? { type: data.type, fields: res } : { type: data.type };

}

let newArr = arr.map(item => modifyArr(item));

console.log(newArr);
```

This will print

```
[
    { type: 'type', fields: ['field1', 'field2'] },
    { type: 'type2' },
    { type: 'type', fields: ['field1', 'field2'] },
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{ type: 'type', fields: ['field1']}, { type: 'type2'}, { type: 'type', fields: ['field2']}];

result = arr.map(({ type }) => {
    const fields = arr.filter((o) => o.type === type).flatMap((e) => e.fields);
    return { type, ...fields[0] ? { fields } : {} };
});

console.log(result);
//[
//    {"type": "type", "fields": ["field1", "field2"]},
//    {"type": "type2"},
//    {"type": "type", "fields": ["field1", "field2"]}
//]
```